# Filtering specific objects in an array based on values inside an array property of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to filter objects in an array that contain specific values inside a property that is an array.
Example, here is my array of objects:

```
[
  {_id: 1, value: ['Row', 'Column']}, 
  {_id: 2, value: []}, 
  {_id: 3, value: ['Row']}, 
  {_id: 4},
  {_id: 5, value: ['Column']}
]
```

I need it to return all objects with 'Row' in the value array, i.e. the result should be:

```
[
  {_id: 1, value: ['Row', 'Column']}, 
  {_id: 3, value: ['Row']},
]
```

Here's my method to do this but it's returning null:

```
findRowValues() {
    let groupObj = [
       {_id: 1, value: ['Row', 'Column']}, 
       {_id: 2, value: []}, 
       {_id: 3, value: ['Row']}, 
       {_id: 4},
       {_id: 5, value: ['Column']}
    ];
    
    return groupObj.filter(function (obj) {
          return (
            obj.value &&
            obj.value.find(o => { o === 'Row' })
          )
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the `{  }` inside the callback of `find`. Those can be removed for implicit return or you need to use `return` keyword explicity. I have used implicit return due to arrow function.

```js
let groupObj = [
          {_id: 1, value: ['Row', 'Column']}, 
          {_id: 3, value: []}, 
          {_id: 5, value: ['Row']}, 
          {_id: 7},
          {_id: 8, value: ['Column']}
    ];


function findRowValues(groupObj) {
    return groupObj.filter(function (obj) {
          return (
            obj.value &&
            obj.value.find(o => o === 'Row' )
          )
    });
}

console.log(findRowValues(groupObj))
```

For `return` key word  - `obj.value.find(o => {return o === 'Row'} )`

Answer (score 0):

Use `destructuring` and `includes` method

```js
function findRowValues() {
  const groupObj = [
    { _id: 1, value: ["Row", "Column"] },
    { _id: 2, value: [] },
    { _id: 3, value: ["Row"] },
    { _id: 4 },
    { _id: 5, value: ["Column"] },
  ];

  return groupObj.filter(({ value = [] }) => value.includes("Row"));
}

console.log(findRowValues())
```